# How to get regex pattern in PHP

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I will get the input of `url` In 4 formats

**Ex urls formats `dadar` and `mumbai` may vary:**

1. /hospitals-in-mumbai
2. /hospitals-in-dadar/mumbai
3. /clinics-in-mumbai
4. /clinics-in-dadar/mumbai

I am validating it using the `regex` pattern in `laravel` validation. The pattern is shown in above four formats.

I have tried many methods but didn't work.

I want help in making regex pattern

Comment: @PatrickQ I have already presented in the question. I want my result should be in the above four formats. **My attempt** : `^hospitals|clinics-in-[[a-z]/[a-z]]|[a-z]$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:

```
#\/hospitals-in-\w+#
#\/hospitals-in-\w+\/\w+#
#\/clinics-in-\w+#
#\/clinics-in-\w+\/\w+#
```

May I also recommend regex101.com for improving your regex skills!

All in one regex https://regex101.com/r/HjOilB/1

```
#\/(hospitals|clinics)-in-\w+(\/\w+)?#
```

Comment: Thank for your support and suggestion. But I will get a single input and there I have to cover all four cases.  I side by side I am also trying to improve my regex.

Comment: all 4 cases in ONE regex?

Comment: Yes. how can we solve it?